# Redirect HTML-page using meta refresh over symbolic link

Tags: html, redirect

I have a simple place-holder html-file that I would want to use the header meta tag to redirect automatically. The target is a symolic link (linux) that points to a git-repo directory.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url="universitetet/">
```

However this simply reloads itself. Giving absolute path does so too.

However, using the javascript solution works (and also normal links work fine).

```
<script language="javascript">
     window.location = "universitetet/";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the extra `"` inside the `content` attribute.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=universitetet/" />
```

Side note: Always provide a plain HTML link (`<a href="universitetet/">Link</a>`), in case the user has disabled meta redirection and/or JavaScript.

Comment: +1 about your side note and you beat me always :D , that what I'm using in my site :)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
<meta content="0; url=(YOUR_LINK)" http-equiv="REFRESH">
```

Working with me, btw your code have issue with quotations: here `content="0; url="universitetet/"`.